# How can I get rid of warnings in Verilog code for 32-bus 8:1 mux?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, multiplexer, system-verilog

```
module mux(In1,In2,In3,In4,In5,In6,In7,In8,s1,Z);
output reg [31:0]Z;
input [31:0]In1,In2,In3,In4,In5,In6,In7,In8;
input [2:0]s1;
wire [7:0]s2;
wire [31:0]X[7:0];
wire [31:0]Y[7:0];

genvar jp,jq;
integer pj,qj;

assign X[0]=In1;
assign X[1]=In2;
assign X[2]=In3;
assign X[3]=In4;
assign X[4]=In5;
assign X[5]=In6;
assign X[6]=In7;
assign X[7]=In8;

and(s2[0],~s1[2],~s1[1],~s1[0]);
and(s2[1],~s1[2],~s1[1],s1[0]);
and(s2[2],~s1[2],s1[1],~s1[0]);
and(s2[3],~s1[2],s1[1],s1[0]);
and(s2[4],s1[2],~s1[1],~s1[0]);
and(s2[5],s1[2],~s1[1],s1[0]);
and(s2[6],s1[2],s1[1],~s1[0]);
and(s2[7],s1[2],s1[1],s1[0]);

for(jp=0;jp<=31;jp=jp+1) begin
    for(jq=0;jq<=31;jq=jq+1) begin
        if(jq<=31) begin
            assign Y[jp][jq]=X[jp][jq]&s2[jp]; // This is the line 33 mentioned in warning
        end
    end
end

always@ * begin
    for(pj=0;pj<=31;pj=pj+1) begin
        Z[pj]=Y[0][pj];
        for(qj=0;qj<=7;qj=qj+1) begin
            Z[pj]=Z[pj]|Y[qj][pj];
        end
end
end
endmodule

module tb;
wire [31:0]Z;
reg [31:0]In1,In2,In3,In4,In5,In6,In7,In8;
reg [2:0]s1;
mux mux(.In1(In1),.In2(In2),.In3(In3),.In4(In4),.In5(In5),.In6(In6),.In7(In7),.In8(In8),.s1(s1),.Z(Z));
initial begin
    $monitor("time=%g sel=%d o/p=%d",$time,s1,Z);
    In1=32'd1;In2=32'd2;In3=32'd3;In4=32'd4;
    In5=32'd5;In6=32'd6;In7=32'd7;In8=32'd8;
    s1=3'b000;
    repeat(7) begin
        #10 s1=s1+1'b1;
    end
end
endmodule
```

The warning was as shown below:

```
m.v:33: warning: ignoring out of bounds l-value array access Y[8].       
m.v:33: warning: ignoring out of bounds l-value array access Y[8].                     
m.v:33: warning: ignoring out of bounds l-value array access Y[8].                                     
m.v:33: warning: ignoring out of bounds l-value array access Y[8].                 
.                                                                         
.                                                                          
.                                                                         
.                                                                               
.                                                                          
m.v:33: warning: ignoring out of bounds l-value array access Y[31].         
m.v:33: warning: ignoring out of bounds l-value array access Y[31].
```

Answer (score 5):

You should write your generate-for loop as

```
  for(genvar jp=0;jp<8;jp++) 
    for(genvar jq=0;jq<32;jq++) 
          assign Y[jp][jq]=X[jp][jq]&s2[jp];
```

Then the complete example would be

```
module mux(
  input wire [31:0]In1,In2,In3,In4,In5,In6,In7,In8,
  input reg [2:0]s1,
  output reg [31:0]Z
);

wire [7:0]s2;
wire [31:0]X[0:7];
wire [31:0]Y[7:0];

assign X={In1,In2,In3,In4,In5,In6,In7,In8};

and(s2[0],~s1[2],~s1[1],~s1[0]);
and(s2[1],~s1[2],~s1[1],s1[0]);
and(s2[2],~s1[2],s1[1],~s1[0]);
and(s2[3],~s1[2],s1[1],s1[0]);
and(s2[4],s1[2],~s1[1],~s1[0]);
and(s2[5],s1[2],~s1[1],s1[0]);
and(s2[6],s1[2],s1[1],~s1[0]);
and(s2[7],s1[2],s1[1],s1[0]);

for(genvar jp=0;jp<8;jp++) 
    for(genvar jq=0;jq<32;jq++) 
          assign Y[jp][jq]=X[jp][jq]&s2[jp];

always_comb
    for(int pj=0;pj<=31;pj=pj++) begin
        Z[pj]=Y[0][pj];
        for(int qj=0;qj<=7;qj++) begin
            Z[pj]=Z[pj]|Y[qj][pj];
        end
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler way to code a 32-bit 8:1 mux in SystemVerilog is to use a `case` statement.  This is the common way to do so:

```
module mux(In1,In2,In3,In4,In5,In6,In7,In8,s1,Z);
output reg [31:0]Z;
input [31:0]In1,In2,In3,In4,In5,In6,In7,In8;
input [2:0]s1;

always_comb begin
    case (s1)
       0: Z = In1;
       1: Z = In2;
       2: Z = In3;
       3: Z = In4;
       4: Z = In5;
       5: Z = In6;
       6: Z = In7;
       7: Z = In8;
    endcase
end
endmodule
```

This avoids the warnings, and shows this output:

```
time=0 sel=0 o/p=         1
time=10 sel=1 o/p=         2
time=20 sel=2 o/p=         3
time=30 sel=3 o/p=         4
time=40 sel=4 o/p=         5
time=50 sel=5 o/p=         6
time=60 sel=6 o/p=         7
time=70 sel=7 o/p=         8
```

---

The reason for the warnings is that you declared `Y` as an array of **8** 32-bit values.  The array indexes range from 0 to 7: `Y[0]` to `Y[7]`.  The problem is that your code tries to index the 8th through 31st element of the array.  In this expression:

```
Y[jp][jq]
```

`jp` is the array index, which should only have values between 0 and 7.  However, your `for` loop runs from 0 to 31 for `jp`:

```
for(jp=0;jp<=31;jp=jp+1) begin
```

As soon as `jp` becomes 8, you start getting the `warning: ignoring out of bounds l-value array access` messages.

The other answer shows the specific fix, if you want to adhere to your original code design; I thought it would be beneficial to provide a detailed explanation of the warnings.